# Facing difficulty in finding a counterexample to prove that the set SL$(n, \Bbb R)$ is not bounded in M$(n, \Bbb R)$ for $n \geq 2$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Facing difficulty in finding a counterexample to prove that the set SL$(n, \Bbb R)$ is not bounded in M$(n, \Bbb R)$ for $n \geq 2$.

Here SL$(n, \Bbb R)$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices whose det is $1$.

Comment: Just take a suitable diagonal matrix.

Comment: will the matrix work?? Diag(n,1/n,1,1....,1)

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this $A=(a_{ij})$ where $a_{11}=1,a_{12}=n,a_{21}=0,a_{22}=1$